# How to retrieve the thrust distribution over a blade using XROTOR?

Tags: aerodynamics, propeller, rotorcraft

What is the procedure for retrieving the thrust distribution over a propeller blade using XROTOR? I need the sectional (i.e., for each station) thrust coefficient values.

I was only able to retrieve the sectional lift and drag coefficients, but I would also need to know the inflow angles to get thrust, which I don't know how to get.